# ZMQ message lost when REQ-Socket has no connected peer

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am trying to create a simple ZMQ REQ-Socket, that connects to a REP-Socket and then sends a request.

The specification at http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:28 says that a REQ-Socket

> SHALL block on sending, or return a suitable error, when it has no
>   connected peers

I tried it with this code:

```cpp
#include <zmq.hpp>
zmq::context_t context;
zmq::socket_t requestSocket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
requestSocket.connect("inproc://test");
requestSocket.send(0, 0);
```

but `send` does not block and does not throw an error. When I create a REP-Socket afterwards it does not receive the message:

```
zmq::socket_t replySocket(context, ZMQ_REP);
replySocket.bind("inproc://test");
zmq::message_t message;
replySocket.recv(&message); //hangs
```

The Missing-Message-Problem-Solver (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Missing-Message-Problem-Solver) says

> Send and receive in a loop and check return codes

but `send` does not throw an error (`zmq_send` returns 0). So what is the correct way to do that?

I am using ZMQ 4.0.3

Remark:
The example above works fine if I

- use other socket types (like `ZMQ_PAIR`)
- or exchange `connect` and `bind`
- or `send` after `bind`

Edit:
It also works fine when I use tcp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is still a limitation of inproc. The ZMQ-Guide says that for inproc sockets `bind` must be called before `connect`. This limitation was fixed in version 4.0.0 but apparently not for REQ-sockets.

Comment: My first guess was going to be `inproc`.  It's usually most straight forward to test with `tcp` *first*, it avoids little edge cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

### Transport-specific step for I/O-Thread-less `inproc` Transport Class

**Connecting an `inproc` socket**

When connecting a socket to a peer ***address***(*) using `zmq_connect()` with the **`inproc`** transport, the ***endpoint*** shall be interpreted as an (*)*arbitrary string* identifying the **<*name*>** to connect to.

The **<*name*>** **must have been previously created** *by assigning* it to **at least one socket** within the ***same*** ØMQ context as the socket being connected.

Create another "stunt"-socket, using `inproc://test` **<*name*>** before your code-segment and the `requestSocket` instance, now being the 2nd socket "under" the hood of the same ZMQ_Context, shall work as per both the specification and your expectation.

---

### A Rule-of-Thumb

It is definitely not a bad practice to detect + handle error-states and handle 'em as a principle -- both in the mock-up code & the more in the production code.

Comment: I know, I found this information here: http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-inproc. But I think the change log is more up-to.date: http://zeromq.org/docs:changes-4-0-0 : You can now connect to an inproc:// endpoint that does not already exist.

Comment: "A Rule-of-Thumb": I disagree. One of the biggest advantages of c++ over c is that you can rely on exceptions. If a function should not fail there is no reason to catch exceptions.